# Why can we define a setter with [[set]] if [[writable]] is false?

Tags: javascript

The [ECMAScript language specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#table-data-property-attributes) defines the [[writable]] attribute of Object.defineProperty() as following:

- If false, attempts by ECMAScript code to change the property's
  [[Value]]
  attribute using [[Set]] will not succeed.

However, this definition doesn't make any sense. There it says that if [[writable]] is false, any attempts to use [[set]] will not work. So in other words: if [[writable]] is false then we can't change it to an accessor property of a setter.

However, in the example below we have an object where we are able to define [[set]] despite [[writable]] being false:

```
var plainObj = new Object();

Object.defineProperty(plainObj, "v1", {
    configurable: true,
    writable: false, //<---- attribute [[writable]] is 'false'
    value: "handsome-and-SKINNY"
});

    //setting an [[set]] attribute:
    Object.defineProperty(plainObj, "v1", {
        set: function (input) {
            console.log("Setter's value: " + input);
        }
    });

    //passing argument to setter
    plainObj.v1 = "passed argument";
```

Console output:

```
Setter's value: passing argument
```

So as you can see, we have successfully defined an [[set]] attribute and passed in some arguments into it, despite the fact that it shoudn't be happening because [[writable]] was set to **false**. Any explenations are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > If false, attempts by ECMAScript code to change the property's [[Value]] attribute using [[Set]] will not succeed.
>
> However, this definition doesn't make any sense. There it says that if [[writable]] is false, any attempts to use [[set]] will not work.

You misunderstood the specification.

When the property is a data property, it is defined by the *[[Value]]* and *[[Writable]]* attributes, *[[Get]]* and *[[Set]]* are not present. When the property is an accessor property, it is defined by the *[[Get]]* and *[[Set]]* attributes, *[[Value]]* and *[[Writable]]* are not present.

The phrase "*change the property's [[Value]] attribute using [[Set]] will not succeed.*" does not refer to the *[[Set]]* attribute of a data property descriptor record, **it refers to the [*[[Set]]()* internal object method](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver)** which will not succeed.

Your example code did change the data property into an accessor property, thereby also removing the *[[Writable]]* attribute. It now can be written to as long as there is a setter.

Answer (score 0):

`writable: false` means that `value: "handsome-and-SKINNY"` is constant:

```
Object.defineProperty(plainObj, "v1", {
    configurable: true,
    writable: false,  // hhh can't be changed
    value: "hhh"
});
plainObj.v1 = "aaa"
console.log(plainObj.v1)
```

```
hhh
```

```
Object.defineProperty(plainObj, "v1", {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,  // hhh can be changed
    value: "hhh"
});
plainObj.v1 = "aaa"
console.log(plainObj.v1)
```

```
aaa
```

Property may be redefined even if value is [not writable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

> writable
> true if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator. Defaults to false.

Comment: @handsome-and-SKINNY While this may really not answer the question you asked, your comment can be seen as rude. That can make people not want to help in the future.

Comment: @FZs Im pretty sure he is going to upvote your comment. And my question has been properly answered by someone else.